# CORS issue with HEROKU after deploying

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cors

So I've got my node.js server that connects to my React app which works completely fine locally. And when I deployed my server to Heroku and changed out localhost with the URL of the deployed app in my local React app I get this lovely CORS preflight request error. I originally thought it was an issue with my environmental variables but that doesn't seem to be the case. Here is the node server.

```
    const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require('cors');
require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: process.env.GM_USER,
    pass: process.env.GM_PASS,
  },
});

app.post("/send", (req, res) => {
  var mailOptions = {
    from: req.body.email,
    to: "test@gmail.com",
    subject: `Hello this is ${req.body.name}`,
    text: `${req.body.message}, 
    From, ${req.body.name}`,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log("Email sent: " + info.response)
      .then(res => res.status(200).send(res));
    }
  });
});

// require("./routes/apiRoutes")(app)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening to port ${port}`);
});
```

I've looked and it seems like people have had similar problems but I can't seem to find a solution. If anyone could help that would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
      res.send(200);
    }
    else {
      next();
    }
};

...
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You already handling `CORS`, I ran into the same problem, I think your should test your server logs. In my case I was having some other issue with packages and it was giving `500` error and also No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header, `CORS` error. When I fixed that issue `CORS` is also resolved.

**Or** you can try intercepting each request and set it for each response.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried intercepting each request but that didn't seem to do anything sadly. The API still works locally but not on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said it doesn't seem to be a problem with environmental variables, but I've ran into this problem 2 if not 3 separate times now, end up searching all these related threads, trying all these different things with CORS, and it has ended up being an environmental variable issue each time!

One time it was that I put ACCESS_ID when it was supposed to be ACCESS_SID (or vice versa, I can't remember).  One time I simply forgot to add the new environmental variables that I added locally because of new features I had added.  Etc.

Anyway, just a reminder to check and double-check that your local environmental variables match what you've added to your deployment platform (e.g. Heroku > Settings > Config Vars), anyone reading this!